How come Selenium can make screenshots of Widevine protected video?
I am using Selenium with Chrome driver for an project, and accidentally found that it is possible to screenshot Widevinew-DRM protected video. For example, using the get_screenshot_as_file() function, I can make a screenshot of an entire webpage opened in the Chrome driver, the content of Widevine protected video can also be captured.
Interestingly, when I use Windows native screenshot tools to take screenshot of the same webpage in the Chrome driver, the video blacks out and I can't capture the content.
I then tried using Edge driver, opened a webpage PlayReady-protected video, and use the same function to make screenshot, and found it is not possible to take screenshots, the video section blacks out as expected.
I also attempted to use JavsScript html2canvas to make a screenshot of the same webpage and found it is unable to capture the content of Widevine-protected video.
I wonder how come Selenium can take screenshots of DRM-protected video, what mechanism Selenium uses to take screenshots?

Hi, no offense but why do you care that it works? Either you want to exploit the mechanism or you want to get it blocked, Neither is good for the rest of world...

The DRM in the player is probably just listening for OS level print screen calls.  (maybe that's even in the video card driver??)  Worth noting that you can also screenshot DRM vids by running an OS in a virtual machine and then taking screenshot from the host OS, so detection must be at OS level.

I believe it's using a framebuffer and a canvas... similar to what you were trying to do.   You can see the spec here: https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver2/#dfn-draw-a-bounding-box-from-the-framebuffer

@VC.One Because I spent quite some time doing a DRM related project before and thus when I found something unintuitive I got very curious how it works/does not work.

@browsermator, thanks, but if this is the case, I think it should be able to successfully take screenshots when I use Edge driver too. Make screenshot of DRM video is not impossible, you only need to disable hardware acceleration. What makes my curious is how can Selenium make screenshots while I can't make it manually using system tools. And it shouldn't be the html-canvas approach because I tried writing code in JS and it couldn't make screenshots.

I linked to the W3C specs for the wire protocol there... it's up to the browsers to implement them, and Microsoft, in particular, always likes to invent its own standards, so... yer results may vary.  I do remember that IE used to be great for taking screenshots, as it was the only browser that would take the full page instead of just the visible viewport.  Don't know if that's relevant here, but shows how different browsers implemented driver commands differently.

In general though the browser is outside of the sandbox so has much more access to things like video-card framebuffers than would JS running inside the sandbox.

"In general though the browser is outside of the sandbox so has much more access to things like video-card framebuffers than would JS running inside the sandbox." -- I agree with what you said, thanks!
